# Rewriting expression without integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Define the function $f$ by
$$f(k)=\begin{cases}
\sqrt{k^2+2\pi k  +\pi^2} &\text{if } k<-\pi       \\ 
\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-k)&\text{if }-\pi\leq   k\leq  \frac{\pi}{2}        \\
1 &\text{if } k> \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{cases} $$
Then, the function may be $G$ defined by 
$$G(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(k) \, \mathrm{d}k $$
where $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$.

How can I express $G(x)$ without the integral sign?

Edit: Changed errors

Comment: What is $t$? Should it be just $k$?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes that $t=k$ in your question.

First note that 
$$
\sqrt{k^2+2\pi k  +\pi^2} = \sqrt{(k+\pi)^2} = |k+\pi|
$$
Now, when $x<-\pi$, 
$$
G(x) = \int_{0}^x f(x) \, \mathrm{d}k = \int_{0}^{-\pi} \cos(\frac{\pi}{2} -k) \, \mathrm{d}k + \int_{-\pi}^x |k+\pi| \, \mathrm{d}k.
$$
We'll consider the second integral on the right hand side first. Since the argument to the absolute value function in integrand is always non-positive over the bounds of the integral, we can take its opposite and drop the absolute value function. This reduces the integral to
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^x |k+\pi| \, \mathrm{d}k &= -\int_x^{-\pi} -(k+\pi) \, \mathrm{d}k = \int_x^{-\pi} (k+\pi) \, \mathrm{d}k \\
&= \left[\frac{1}{2}k^2 + \pi k\right]_x^{-\pi} = \left[\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi^2 - \pi^2\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \pi x\right) \right] \\ 
&= -\frac{1}{2}x^2 - \pi x - \frac{1}{2} \pi ^2
\end{align}
The first integral on the right hand side is evaluates to $2$, and so the first case boils down to
\begin{align}
G(x) &=  -\frac{1}{2}x^2 - \pi x - \frac{1}{2} \pi ^2 + 2 \\ 
 &= -\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2 + 2\pi x + \pi ^2 \right) +2\\
 &= -\frac{1}{2}(x+\pi)^2+2
\end{align}

Now lets consider the value of $G$ for $-\pi < x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. This is as simple as evaluating the definite integral
$$
G(x) = \int_0^x \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} -k\right) \, \mathrm{d}k.
$$
Note that $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} -k) = \sin k$ for all $k \in \mathbb R$, Hence for $-\pi < x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, we have
$$
G(x) = \int_0^x \sin k \, \mathrm{d} k = \left[-\cos k\right]_0^x = -\cos (x) + 1
$$

Finally, let's look at $G(x)$ for $x > \frac{\pi}{2}$. Observe that 
$$
G(x) = \int_0^x f(k) \, \mathrm{d}k = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} -k\right) \, \mathrm{d}k + \int_\frac{\pi}{2}^x 1 \, \mathrm{d}k
$$
The first integral on the right hand side is simply $1$ and the integrand of the second is a constant function, so this case simplifies to 
$$
G(x) = 1 + \left[k\right]_{\pi/2}^x = x + 1 - \frac{\pi}{2}
$$
Putting everything together, we have

$$
G(x) = \begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{2}(x+\pi)^2+2, &  \phantom{-}x < - \pi\\ 
-\cos (x) + 1, & -\pi\leq   x\leq  \frac{\pi}{2} \\
x + 1 - \frac{\pi}{2}, & \phantom{-}x> \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Break it up into 3 cases:

$\underline{ case \space 1:}$ $x <-\pi$ giving 
$$G(x) = \int_0^{-\pi}cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-k)dk + \int_{-\pi}^x \sqrt{k^2+2\pi k + \pi^2}dk$$

$\underline{case \space 2:}$ $-\pi \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ giving

$$G(x) = \int_0^{x}cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-k)dk$$

$\underline{case \space 3:}$ $x > \frac{\pi}{2}$ giving

$$G(x) = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-k)dk + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^x dk$$

Compute these integrals and you'll have $G(x)$ without any integrals.